# Usar ruta hija de módulo externo al principal importada con loadChildren como predefinida del proyecto

Tags: angular, routes

Actualmente tengo un proyecto, el cual tiene diferentes módulos cada uno con su archivo routing. Uno de estos módulos es el módulo 'authentication', el cual presenta componentes y layouts como puede ser la página de login, reset de contraseña etc.

Las rutas de este módulo son importadas a través de loadChildren al archivo routing principal de esta forma:

**App routing:**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/authentication/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'authentication',
    component: AppBlankComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./authentication/authentication.module').then((m) => m.AuthenticationModule),
      },
    ],
  },
  [...]
```

**Authentication routing:**

```
export const AuthenticationRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '404',
    component: ErrorComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'lockscreen',
    component: LockscreenComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
  }
];
```

El archivo authentication.routing.ts es importado en authentication.module.ts:
`RouterModule.forChild(AuthenticationRoutes),`
Necesito que cuando se acceda directamente a la página raíz del proyecto (en caso de desarrollo localhost:4200) el cliente sea redirigido directamente a localhost:4200/authentication/login.

Para ello había añadido la siguiente línea al inicio de app routing:
`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/authentication/login', pathMatch: 'full' },`
Pero no realiza ninguna acción, se queda la página en blanco, en cambio si añado la ruta /authentication/login manualmente si me carga el layout y los componentes deseados.

Es decir, necesito que una ruta de un módulo externo al principal que es importada a través de loadChildren sea la ruta predefinida siempre que se acceda a la web.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.